# Обернуть блок в ссылку , которая находиться в этом блоке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, href

Есть множество блоков данной конструкции:

```
    <div class="thumbnail boxed-content">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h3 class="item-title text-danger center-block"> 
                    <a title="DP2K-6E" href="/some.html">asdasd</a> 
                </h3>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Как обернуть каждый в ссылку и поставить атрибут href такой, который находиться внутри этого блока.
Делал так, но что-то пошло не так:

```
$('.thumbnail.boxed-content').wrap("<a href=$('this .col-sm-12:nth-child(2) h3 a').href></a>");
```

Comment: Ссылка в ссылке? Так нельзя.

Comment: @MAX можно, ответ ниже подходит, но подставляет только первую попавшуюся ссылку

Comment: Нельзя по стандарту HTML5. Ссылка может оборачивать любой блок, при условии, что в блоке нет ссылок. То есть ссылку в ссылке сделать нельзя. Ну, а по самому коду, понятно, что как угодно можно расставить. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $blocks = $('.thumbnail.boxed-content');
var $hrefs = $('.thumbnail.boxed-content a');

$blocks.wrap(function(){
 var $element = $(this);
 var href = $element.find('a').attr('href');
 return "<a href="+href+"></a>"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thumbnail boxed-content">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h3 class="item-title text-danger center-block"> 
                    <a title="DP2K-6E" href="/some1.html">first block</a> 
                </h3>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail boxed-content">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h3 class="item-title text-danger center-block"> 
                    <a title="DP2K-6E" href="/some2.html">second block</a> 
                </h3>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!

Answer (score 0):

***Вот, попробуй этот код использовать!!!***

```
const href = $('h3.item-title>a').attr("href");
$('.thumbnail,.boxed-content').wrap('<a href="'+href+'"></a>');
```

Comment: этот код оборачивает все блоки в первую попавщуюся ссылку. Надо учитывать , что в каждом блоке - своя ссылка